# Vide et plein sont à la fois nom[s] et adjectif[s]

Tags: accord, typographie

Typographie  "normale" :

> 1n — *Vide* et *plein* sont à la fois nom et adjectif
> 2n — *Vide* et *plein* sont à la fois noms et adjectifs

Avec une typographie qui met l’accent sur la qualité du mot

> 1i — *Vide* et *plein* sont à la fois *nom* et *adjectif*
> 2i — *Vide* et *plein* sont à la fois *noms* et *adjectifs*

> 1a — *Vide* et *plein* sont à la fois "nom" et "adjectif"
> 2a — *Vide* et *plein* sont à la fois "noms" et "adjectifs"

NB : les guillemets français « vide » ne sont pas inclus mais on peut aussi utiliser les apostrophes ‘plein’

*Les interrogations* :

— Y a-t-il une règle absolue que régie les propositions 1* et 2*,
— Est-ce que la typographie permet de contourner cette éventuelle règle,
— Parmi les deux typographies y en a-t-il une qui est plus intuitive,
— Parmi les deux typographies y en a-t-il une proposition qui serait une [tautologie](https://www.cnrtl.fr/lexicographie/tautologie)

Comment: Encore un vote négatif, furtif et honteux car non motivé

Answer (score 1):

Avec des adjectifs, l'accord (2*) est, je pense la règle :

> Vide et plein sont à la fois masculin**s** et monosyllabique**s**.

Avec les substantifs que sont *nom* et *adjectif*, le pluriel est plus courant mais l'usage est libre<sup>1</sup> :

> Vide et plein sont à la fois (des) noms et (des) adjectifs.

> Vide et plein sont à la fois (un) nom et (un) adjectif.

L'utilisation d'italiques ou de guillemets pour *nom(s)* et *adjectif(s)* ne me semble pas très justifiée puisque ces mots sont employés pour ce qu'ils sont, alors que la même utilisation pour *vide* et *plein* permet de comprendre immédiatement de l'utilisation [métalinguistique](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%A9talinguistique) de ces mots. Pour mettre l'accent sur *noms* et *adjectifs*, on pourrait utiliser des caractères gras :

> *Vide* et *plein* sont à la fois **noms** et **adjectifs**.

<sup>1</sup> <sub>Il existe des cas où le singulier s'impose : ***Les** États-Unis sont à la fois **le** pays de la tolérance, plaçant la liberté au-dessus de tout, **et** (**le** pays) de l'intolérance, du fait du poids de la religion et de la morale.* - *50 idées reçues sur les Etats-Unis*, Pascal Boniface, Charlotte Lepri</sub>

Comment: Belle réponse — Pour ne pas tromper la lecture usuelle, j'utilise presque naturellement *2n* dans la majorité des cas, ici *1i* plus didactique, mais pour l'expression poétique (qui traite de l'indicible, et se joue des sens cachés des mots et de leur musique sans les contraintes de la poésie ‘académique’) le *1n*,  ce qui devrait être cohérent avec  les métalinguistes (inconnu·e·s des dicos :-).